# Sublime Text 2 key settings override zen coding settings

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I have installed zen coding in Sublime Text 2 on windows 7. But the shortcuts for html and css  are not working as it works on my mac. For eg: if we expand rz, the result should be resize: but the ST2 expands it to background-size:. I have tried changing autocomplete option to false in Preferences.Sublime-settings file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like CSS fuzzy autocomplete mode is on in old Zen Coding plugin.
Try new plugin instead: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime